# Pandas dataframe sharing between functions isn't working

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-asyncio

I have a script that modifies a pandas dataframe with several concurrent functions (`asyncio` coroutines). Each function adds rows to the dataframe and it's important that the functions all share the same list. However, when I add a row with `pd.concat` a new copy of the dataframe is created. I can tell because each dataframe now has a different memory location as given by `id()`.

As a result the functions are no longer share the same object. How can I keep all functions pointed at a common dataframe object?

Note that this issue doesn't arise when I use the `append` method, but that is being deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

pandas dataframes are efficient because they use contiguous memory blocks, frequently of fundamental types like int and float. You can't just add a row because the dataframe doesn't own the next bit of memory it would have to expand into. Concatenation usually requires that new memory is allocated and data is copied. Once that happens, referrers to the original dataframe

If you know the final size you want, you can preallocate and fill. Otherwise, you are better off keeping a list of new dataframes and concatenating them all at once. Since these are parallel procedures, they aren't dependent on each others output, so this may be a feasable option.

Comment: What's interesting is that it's possible to append rows and columns without changing the object that the variable references. For example:  
    `df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,1,2,3],'B': [10,20,30,40]})`  
If I add a new row and column, printing out the memory address before and after:  
    `print(hex(id(df)))`  
    `df.loc[5,'D']=444`  
    `print(hex(id(df)))`  
I get the same address. I know the memory allocation has changed underneath, but `df` remains a solid reference that I can count on.

Comment: Actually, no. A `DataFrame` is an object that holds a collection of numpy arrays. The arrays can be created, copied, moved or destroyed within the dataframe without the dataframe itself needing to be destroyed. Do `a = df.A` _before_ adding the `D` column and then check `a is df.A` afterwards. Pandas had to create an entirely new A column to add the NaN at the end. If one thread is enumerating A while another thread causes a new A to be created, they will be working on different things.